# Pandas DateTime is automatically switching month and date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Segment on the left is original copy of the Column 'Open'. On the right, after applying datetime, everything is okay except from row 3, date and day interchange all the way till row 12. Why is this happening? Solutions?

[image]

Comment: I got the solution after using %y instead of %Y since year was in two digits in original column, however I still don't understand how it got wrong and why it got right.

Comment: Probably related to that the format doesn't match? The year, like you just wote. Still surprising. (The %d and %m are also supposed to be zero-padded, so those strictly don't match either, but that seems to be fine according to strptime in module datetime).

Comment: Which pandas version? So that we can reproduce it. And what's the exact dtype of the input.

Comment: I'm using v1.1.5 and the input column was of dtype Object. I tried changing the input column to str and still using %Y, it said format doesn't match, but works with %y.
However, I am unable to reproduce the error with the original dtype. Curious.

Comment: Tried using `format="%d/%m/%y"`? Note that parsing directive has to match the input *exactly*. If you don't provide a `format`, pandas to_datetime assumes month-first.